# Challenges of using AWS Lambda chain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-step-functions

**Context:**
I have a pipeline of 6 lambda functions (chained together), triggered by an SNS notification which is generated whenever a file lands on S3. This pipeline essentially takes the file(few GBs), filters it (Spark cluster is created to run the job, then deleted at the end), and inserts it into a DB. Lambdas are orchestrating the flow.

**Issues:**
If one Lambda fails, the chain breaks hence no effective failure handling. Secondly, we experience timeouts if a polling/computation takes longer than 5 minutes, so no effective retry. It takes a long time to test/debug an issue if a lambda fails. Also there is no visibility, say for example how many jobs failed and how many passed? we dont know. Getting a bunch of SNS notifications on email is not very effective/helpful. If the chain breaks, we cannot perform cleanup operations like deleting SPark cluster or housekeeping steps.

**My Questions:**
Is AWS Step Functions a good choice for solving the above issues? When would you not use a Step Function service? If you cannot invoke Step Function through SNS, then what would be the best way to call it whenever a file lands on S3? Feel free to share any other approach to easily and effectively tackle this usecase.

Comment: May get more answers on https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Looks like this will be useful to you. https://read.acloud.guru/how-the-saga-pattern-manages-failures-with-aws-lambda-and-step-functions-bc8f7129f900

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can define catch handlers in your Step Function to handle failing lambdas and rerun them, or do whatever you need on failures.

Here's an example of triggering Step Functions from file uploads to S3: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/synchronizing-amazon-s3-buckets-using-aws-step-functions/

That said, if all you need is a simple re-try logic, you might be able to get there faster using SQS. When SQS clients receive messages from the queue, they are not actually removed immediately, but rather SQS puts a hold on the messages. If a client doesn't delete the messages within a certain time, then those messages are put back into the queue.

Unfortunately, there's currently no way to trigger lambdas directly from SQS, but you can set up one or more CloudWatch events to poll SQS at regular intervals.

Comment: Thanks Kim, but I read that Lambda functions are retried 3 times before failing, so then how Step functions bring value ?

Comment: @obaid Lambda functions are only retried automatically 3 times if they are invoked asynchronously (such as by an SNS trigger).  Step functions invokes them synchronously so the retry logic must be defined by the state machine itself.

Comment: Now we can trigger lambdas from sqs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html